# jQuery selector to ignore specified element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

Consider this DOM :

```
<div id="div1">
  <div class="no-select-inside">
    <p>Don't select me</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Select me</p>
    <div><p>Select me too</p></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Select me</p>
    <div><p>Select me too</p></div>
  </div>
  <footer class="no-select-inside">
    <p>Don't select me</p>
    <div><p>Not me</p></div>
  </footer>
  <section>
    <p>Select me</p>
    <div><p>Select me too</p></div>
  </section>
</div>
```

I want a **fast** and **reliable** jquery (or bare DOM) selector to select those `p` tags that not inside 'no-select-inside' class

Everything is dynamic, but I can assign an attribute to not selectable DOM element.

### **Edit**

The real test case isn't a class selector (maybe a complex attribute selector, ...)

Everything is dynamic and could be too deep nested (100 down to DOM tree under a `no-select-inside` there is `p` that has a `no-select-inside` parent and with all the answer even those elements are selected)

I have all `no-select-inside` cached (Backbone's $el and can be cached in an array for performance) but real problem is selecting those elements in a fast way (20ms in chrome is too slow!).

Answer (score 4):

The general-purpose solution would be to `filter` out those that have a `.no-select-inside` ancestor, for example:

```
$("p")
    .filter(function() { return !$(this).closest(".no-select-inside").length;})
    // and now do what needs to be done
```

This should be reasonably efficient because it only goes over the whole document just once.

Comment: Great, but is it fast enough to use it for lots of elements and deep nested elements?

Comment: @KiTO: Only you can decide that, by measuring on a data set of the appropriate size. If there is any assumptions you can make about the document structure then baking them into the selection might also speed it up, although that depends on the specifics.

Comment: I have all the `no-select-inside` selected before (and was cached).

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/AyPNx/) fiddle shows a simple not selector is faster! (20ms isn't much time but in more than 100 select it's slow!), caching reduced time to 6ms (and even that is slow enough to feel)

Comment: @KiTO: If 6ms is slow then perhaps you should rethink why you need to do this. Perhaps there are better solutions.

Comment: Yep, there must be another and better solution.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) or [:not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) to filter out the `p` elements inside `no-select-inside`

```
$('#div1 p').not('.no-select-inside p')
$('#div1 p:not(.no-select-inside p)')
```

Comment: It's faster than first answer but it's slow! (see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AyPNx/)).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('div:not(.no-select-inside) p')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use .not as the working example is here 

$(document).ready(function(){
     var abc = $('#div1').find("p").not('.no-select-inside p');
     $(abc).each(function(e){
        alert($(this).html());
     }); 
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8F7Kc/14/